# how secure is a mobile website developed using moovweb

Tags: moovweb

I want to know, if I am developing some website that involves making banking transactions etc. How much safe is it to develop it in moovweb platform. Does moovweb provides some extra security measures or any external user can hack the layer developed using Moovweb?

Answer (score 1):

Moovweb has been architected with two guiding principles:

- Stateless system. The Moovweb Platform does not maintain state; all operations are processed in real time.
- Personally Identifiable Information is never stored.

Moovweb is a Level 1 service provider under the Payment Card Industry (PCI) Data Security Standard (DSS) and is HIPAA (Health Insurance Portability and Accountability Act) compliant.